# Removing lines between columns in datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Quick question, Is there any way to remove the lines between columns in a datagrid? I've only seen one answer on SO and it was in regards to WPF, and was not relevant to winforms.

I'm starting to think it may be something super simple, or perhaps the opposite and i'll have to override the draw functions (Which is more effort than it's worth and i'll probably leave it).

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is to change the border style (also see other **Horizontal* styles) by modifying the `CellBorderStyle` property in property inspector or in the code:

```
dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;
```

It always helps to look up the control documentation in MSDN :)

Comment: I had a quick glance through the documentation, must have completely skipped past this part! I'll give it a try.

Comment: No problem, there are many properties there, it is easy to miss it.